# Orbeon controls displayed incorrectly in IFRAME

Tags: orbeon

Just upgraded to Orbeon 4.10 from 4.4 and am having an odd problem with the visual look of forms in the browser.

If I open the form using a URL of the form "http://../orbeon/fr/app-name/form-name/new", it displays as I expect (that is, it matches what I see in the Form Builder application).

On the other hand, if I embed that same URL in an IFRAME within an existing page, the layout of the controls on the form are lost - instead of getting my controls arranged neatly in grids as I see them in Form Builder, I get a single control per line. Even the various submit buttons at the bottom of the page are displayed as separate lines rather than one next to the other.

The same form definition works properly in Orbeon 4.4 - any idea what I need to do in order to get my controls to display properly? Is there some sort of new property here that controls this sort of thing?

Comment: This is strange indeed. What the browser shows in the iframe should be the same as what the browser would have shown had it displayed that URL in a separate window. I'm wondering if it could be a CSS caching problem. This is a long shot, but could you try doing a [force refresh](http://refreshyourcache.com/), if you haven't tried this already?

Comment: Yes, I did try refreshing, purging the cache, restarting the browser - no difference. There's not much to the page containing the Iframe, so it has me stumped as well. We've been using this technique for years without issue. We had tried 4.7 a few months back, and I don't recall seeing this problem with that release.

Comment: This morning we replaced Orbeon 4.10 with 4.9, and things are working as expected once again. This is definitely an issue with something that changed between Orbeon 4.9 and 4.10.

Comment: This is really strange indeed. I'd like to figure this one out, otherwise you might find this one again when upgrading the future, but for this I would need to have some test case I can reproduce. If you have the bandwidth to do so, would you be able to create such a minimal example, starting from a "verbatim" 4.10 build?

Comment: I was able to validate that even a nearly empty two-column form has the same problem on a 4.10 with all defaults. I installed the WAR file in a Tomcat 7 server running Java 1.7, created a form with two columns, placed the URL for the form in our IFRAME URL, and same problem occurs. The IFRAME is coded this way: <iframe border="0" name="iframe" src="/orbeon/fr/orbeon/test/new" width="100%" height="2400" scrolling="yes" resize="" frameborder="0" onload="document.getElementById('loadImg').style.display='none';"></iframe>.

Comment: The HTML document containing the IFRAME does bring in a number of Javascript elements, including some that seem to also be used by Orbeon...I wonder if perhaps this might be part of the problem, although I thought (as you said) that the IFRAME should work no matter what.

Comment: Got it. I think I would need to get to a point where I can reproduce the problem to make progress on this. Would you be able to share with us a jsFiddle that does the inclusion using an `<iframe>`, maybe even pointing to a form on demo.orbeon.com?

Comment: Afraid I'm going to need to put this one on hold for now because it's looking non-trivial to setup...jsFiddle requires the target of the <iframe> to be HTTPS, and demo.orbeon.com isn't setup for this. Likewise, a lot of the Javascript libraries we bring in are http only, so I'd need to do quite a bit of work to move this stuff around. Next time we have 4.10 installed, I'll see if I can set aside a sample on one of our systems and I'll post the URL here.

Comment: Mmmh… maybe you can use http://jsbin.com/ then, as it still doesn't go through HTTPS.